# Custom robots.txt being overwritten in Azure IIS 8 by something

Tags: iis, azure, robots.txt

We have a custom robots.txt in the root of our IIS cloud service Azure website that does not display correctly when navigating to www.oursite.com/robots.txt .  A “different” robots.txt file displays containing:

```
User-agent: LinkChecker  
Allow: /  
User-agent: *  
Disallow: /
```

**We’ve tried:**
 1. Deleting robots.txt file in root  –  the incorrect robots.txt file still displays.
 2. Add url-rewrite rule to web.config to display  custom robots.txt  –  correct robots.txt will display for some time, then revert to different one

Any idea what is stepping on our custom robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS management tools for maintenance, it seems that might already have it's own settings which it presumably overwrites - if you've not configured it in the appropriate place:
[IIS Robots and Sitemap extension](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/iis-search-engine-optimization-toolkit/managing-robotstxt-and-sitemap-files)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites generally frowns on this type of answer because other websites may move, get deleted, or changed. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: Uh, well I just provided the resource for extra information. I did answer the question of "Any idea what is stepping on our custom robots.txt?" - it just seemed to me that there might be other possible problems.